# Power series solution about the regular singular point $x_0=0$ of $x^2\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-x\frac{dy}{dx}+(x^2+1)y=0.$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-writing

Find a power series solution about the regular singular point $x_0=0$ of the differential equation: $$x^2\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-x\frac{dy}{dx}+(x^2+1)y=0.$$

My Attempt:

We assume the power series solution to be of the form $y=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_nx^{n+r},$ such that $c_0\neq 0.$

Now, $y'=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+r)c_nx^{n+r-1}$ and $y''=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+r)(n+r-1)c_nx^{n+r-2}.$ Substituting these values in the given differential equation  (,we apply method of Frobenius), we have,

$$x^2\frac{d^2y}{dy^2}-x\frac{dy}{dx}+(x^2+1)y=0\implies x^2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+r)(n+r-1)c_nx^{n+r-2}-x\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+r)c_nx^{n+r-1}+(x^2+1)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_nx^{n+r}=0\implies \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+r)(n+r-1)c_nx^{n+r}-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+r)c_nx^{n+r}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_nx^{n+r+2}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_nx^{n+r}=0\implies \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+r)(n+r-1)c_nx^{n+r}-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+r)c_nx^{n+r}+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}c_{n-2}x^{n+r}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_nx^{n+r}=0\implies \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}((n+r)(n+r-1)c_n-(n+r)c_n+c_{n-2}+c_n)x^{n+r}+r(r-1)c_0x^r+r(r+1)c_1x^{r+1}-rc_0x^r+c_0x^r+c_1x^{r+1}=0.$$

Thus, we have,

$$r(r-1)-r+1=(r-1)^2=0\implies r=1.$$ So, the indicial equation has two equal roots $r=1.$ We observe,
$$r(r+1)c_1+c_1=0\implies c_1=0.$$

The recurrence relation is, $$(n+r)(n+r-1)c_n-(n+r)c_n+c_{n-2}+c_n=0\implies (n+1)(n)c_n-(n+1)c_n+c_{n-2}+c_n=0\implies (n^2)c_n+c_{n-2}=0\implies c_n=\frac{-c_{n-2}}{n^2},n\geq 2.$$

Thus, we see $c_2=\frac{-c_{0}}{4},$ if $n=2.$

If $n=3$, then $c_3=\frac{-c_{1}}{9}=0,$ and hence all odd coefficients are zero.

If $n=4$ then, $c_4=\frac{-c_{2}}{16}=\frac{c_0}{64}.$

$y=y_1=x^r(c_0+c_1x+c_2x^2+c_3x^3+c_4x^4+...)=c_0x(1-\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{x^4}{64}-...).$

Now, this is the first solution. For the second solution, we apply the method of reduction of order. We consider the second solution as $y_2(x)=y_{11}(x)v(x),$  where $y_{11}(x)=y_1(x)$ with $c_0=1.$ We know that, $$v(x)=\int \frac{e^{-\int(\frac{a_1(x)}{a_0(x)})}}{[y_{11}(x)]^2},$$ if the differential equation is $a_0(x)\frac{d^2y}{dy^2}+a_1(x)\frac{dy}{dx}+a_2(x)y=0.$

Thus, in this case, $a_0(x)=x^2$ and $a_1(x)=-x$ and so, $$v(x)=\int \frac{e^{\int(\frac{1}{x})}}{[y_{11}(x)]^2}=\int \frac{x}{[x(1-\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{x^4}{64}-...)]^2}.$$

So, we have, the second solution as $y_2(x)=c_1y_{11}v(x),$ where $c_1$ is an arbitary constant just like $c_0$. This leads us to the general solution of this equation as $y(x)=c_0y_1(x)+c_1y_2(x).$

But the problem is, I dont know, how to evaluate $$\int \frac{x}{[x(1-\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{x^4}{64}-...)]^2}.$$ Is there any way to calculate this ?

*Also, can my solution as written, be considered a valid one? I say this, because I haven't calculated the integral. But my question is, if we keep the integral as it is, and do the solution just like I did, can this be an accepted solution ? (Or, is it better to have the integral calculated than to leave it as it is ?) Any suggestions, regarding this will be helpful.*

Comment: Judging from WA, the substitution $z(x)=y(x)/x$ converts this into the zeroth-order Bessel equation. So trying to do this problem “from scratch” may end to reinventing that particular wheel.

Comment: @Semiclassical  I don't understand what you mean by "WA" ? But isn't Bessel Equation is of the form $x^2\frac{d^2y}{dy^2}+x\frac{dy}{dx}+(x^2-p^2)y=$ so, $p^2\geq 0$. But here, $x^2\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-x\frac{dy}{dx}+(x^2+1)y=0$, $-1\lt 0$ .

Comment: WA = WolframAlpha—I get so used to citing it that I forget it’s not obvious. Based on using that, my claim is that your differential equation for $y$ turns into Bessel’s equation upon substituting $y=xz$.

Comment: @Semiclassical Oh! That might be true. But, what about my method ?